# Is it the Windows system time could retreat occasionally

Tags: windows, spring-boot, operating-system

`Spring boot` project, log how many time took to save 2 DB,

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();    
getDao().batchInsert(batchList);
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
log.info("Save {} data 2 DB successfully took time: {}", getDescName(), (end - start));
```

Very strangely, I found there is situation time cost is negative，see below

```
2019-05-16 14:41:04.420  INFO 3324 --- [ave2db-thread-2] c.c.sz_vss.demo.AbstractSave2DBProcess   : Save Stock data 2 DB batch size: 416
2019-05-16 14:41:03.152  INFO 3324 --- [ave2db-thread-2] c.c.sz_vss.demo.AbstractSave2DBProcess   : Save Stock data 2 DB successfully took time: -1268
```

Why does this happen? Is it spring boot log system bug? or is it the Windows system time could retreat occasionally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Network time synchronization can apply a correction in either direction, so yes the system calendar can move backwards.  Also in timezones that observe daylight savings time, you will see +/- 1 hour discontinuities each year.

That's why it is not recommended to use the system calendar for measuring elapsed time.  There are monotonic timers (on Windows, `QueryPerformanceCounter()` combined with `QueryPerformanceFrequency()`, on POSIX such as Linux it is `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC)`).  Managed frameworks usually wrap these in an object named "Stopwatch".

Comment: Thanks! In java could use `System.nanoTime()`. `This method can only be used to measure elapsed time and is not related to any other notion of system or wall-clock time.”`